# What does "much" add to the meaning of "How 'much' common were these crimes?"

Tags: adverbs

The dictionary I consulted says that *how much* is used for asking or saying what the amount of something is:

> (1) How *much* common were these crimes?
>
> (2) How common were these crimes?

But, after reading (1) and (2) I don't still understand:

- How are they different?
- What is "the amount of something" to which *how much* refers in case (1)?

Comment: The main difference is that (1) isn't correct English and (2) is.

Comment: @Nigel, if (1) is not correct, how the concept of "commonness" can be quantified?

Comment: Asking "How common is x" is enough to get an answer in terms of commonness - you don't need any more than that.

Comment: *How much ADJECTIVE* is not idiomatic English. May we ask where you found this?

Comment: @Carlo_R.  was the dictionary a bi-lingual one? *Quanto* is usually translated into "how much" therefore, "Quanto erano comune...?" someone *might* erroneously translate the phrase into: "How much common were (plural noun) ?"!

Comment: @Mari-Lou, Italians say "Quanto erano comuni ..." (note the "i" at the end of "comuni"), so, yes, you are perfectly right in identifying the problem from which the question arose.

Comment: @Carlo_R. My written Italian has always been my Achilles heel, thank you for correcting me. (Lets hope for me, Italian language & Usage becomes reality!)

Answer (score 6):

*How* carries the sense of measure—of quantity, amount or degree—**in itself**, and takes an adjective or adverb to define **what** is to be measured:

> How *quickly* did he run?  ... you are asking for the measure of quickness, a speed.
>   How *much* money did he have? ... you are asking for the measure of muchness, an amount.
>   How *many* hamburgers can he eat? ... you are asking for the measure of manyness, a number.
>   How *big* is his house? ... you are asking for the measure of bigness, a size.

So when you ask "How *common*", there is no need for another adjective to specify that you are asking for a measure of commonness. That's what *How?* means, all by itself.

Consequently, *How much common* is not idiomatic English.

Comment: Neat examples! I really like "muchness" and "manyness" there! It's not often you need words like that though (my browser spellchecker is unhappy about the latter! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers The credit is Carlo_R's: he set it up in his comment "how the concept of commonness can be quantified".

Comment: It might be worth noting that *how* can mean either *to what degree*, or *in what way*. Those two senses aren't always completely distinct - *"How difficult can walking and chewing gum be?"* would normally mean much the same as *"How can walking and chewing gum be difficult?"*. But there *is* likely to be a difference in meaning between *"How common is immortality?"* and *"How is immortality common?"* (the first version asks *to what degree*, the second *in what way*).